# Sphinx search: bug in handling multiple blend_chars in a single term?

Tags: sphinx

I'm using Sphinx 2.2.11 and believe I've found a bug regarding how Sphinx indexes terms that contain more than one instance of a blend character.

For example, I have the hyphen and period set as blend_chars:

```
blend_chars = ., -
```

Let's say I have a term in the database as follows:

```
part1-part2.part3
```

I would expect that Sphinx would index this term in all possible combinations for each blend_char. For example:

- Variant 1: `part1-part2.part3`
- Variant 2: `part1 part2.part3`
- Variant 3: `part1-part2 part3`
- Variant 4: `part1 part2 part3`

However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

If I search for:

```
part2.part3
```

I don't find the record containing the term `part1-part2.part3`.

However, if I search for:

```
part2 part3
```

OR

```
part1 part2 part3
```

I do find the record.

This suggests to me that Sphinx does not index all possible combinations of the blend_chars. Instead, it appears to index just two versions:

1. `part1-part2.part3` (with blend_chars intact)
2. `part1 part2 part3` (with blend_chars ignored, treated as whitespace)

If true, I would consider this a bug, as it tends to break searches that use just one of the blend_chars.

Can anyone confirm that they are seeing the same behavior? And can anyone suggest tips on how to fix or work around it?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `blend_chars = ., -` and **search** for `part2.part3` or `part1-part2` Sphinx leaves those as single tokens, it doesn't convert them to `part2 AND part3` and `part1 AND part2`.

BUT when you **index** `part1-part2.part3` it generates 4 tokens: `part1-part2.part3`, `part1`, `part2` and `part3`. That's why you can't find neither of them with `part1-part2` or `part2.part3`.

The solution is to not use blended chars in your query. If you want to automate it you can use `CALL KEYWORDS` to see how it would be tokenized during indexation prior to your search query and then use the results to modify your query, e.g.:

```
mysql> call keywords('part1-part2.part3', 'blend');
+------+-------------------+-------------------+
| qpos | tokenized         | normalized        |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 1    | part1-part2.part3 | part1-part2.part3 |
| 1    | part1             | part1             |
| 2    | part2             | part2             |
| 3    | part3             | part3             |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```